# ajaxForm Event Delegation

Tags: jquery, ajaxform, event-delegation

I have a form and i use ajaxForm to handle the submit, the problem is i can't submit the form twice after the first success(this works already) since it lost the event handler. I tried with event delegation but what i get is the default browser behaviour again, not passing though ajaxForm, i debugged with alert('') and it triggers the submit handler everytime. I am learning so any help, explain would be very helpful

Jquery

```
$(document).on('submit', "#form",function() {
$(this).ajaxForm( {
    target: '#preview',
    success: function() {
        $('.box-search').slideUp('slow');
        $('#form').trigger("reset");
      }
   });
});
```

it could be prevent default?

HTML FORM

```
         <div class="box-search">
            <form action="assets/php/insert-comment.php" method="POST" id="form">
                <div class="container search-box">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col l12 s8 center offset-s2">
                            <input type="text" name="book_name" id="books" autocomplete="off" required/>
                             <label for="books">Busca un Libro...</label>
                            <div class="result"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 no-display">
                            <textarea name="comment_name" id="textarea" class="materialize-textarea" maxlength="250" data-length="250"></textarea>
                            <label for="textarea">Comentario...</label>
                            <input type="submit" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </form>
        </div>
        <div class="padding" id="preview"></div>
```

PHP FILE insert-comment.php

```
   <?php
    include("conectar.php");
    $link = Conectarse();
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
      $book=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['book_name']);
      $comment=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment_name']);
      if(strlen($book)>0 && strlen($comment)>0)
      {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (name_Book,comment) 
      VALUES('$book','$comment')", $link);
      echo "<h3>Tu comentario se registr&oacute; con &eacute;xito. ¡Muchas 
      Gracias! 
      </h3>";
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: try `$(document).on('click', "#submit",function()` and `$("#form").ajaxForm`

Comment: default browser behaviour =/

its works once via Ajax if i remove  "$(document).on('submit', "#form",function() "

Comment: change `$(document).on('click', "#submit",function(e) `and add `e.preventDefault();` before  `$("#form").ajaxForm`

Comment: tried but again default behaviour :( #submit reference to all submits? note that my submit has no id

Comment: `#submit` mean your submit button. you have to add

Comment: do you have a codepen or something ? and why do you use ajaxForm ? you know it's not really ajax right ?

Comment: i dont know men, its the solution i found.Yes i have the page on a host but i should explain to you how to get into that behaviour, so if you want..